# How can I dynamically find the height of a flexbox item, as the window resizes, with jquery, and use it to dynamically add height with an animation?

Tags: jquery, flexbox

I am using a flexbox to create my vertical navbar. Here is the relevant HTML for it:

```
<div id="navbar">
    <div class="nav-pill">About Me</div>
    <div class="nav-pill">Awards</div>
    <div class="nav-pill">Hobbies</div>
    <div class="nav-pill">Coding YT</div>
    <div class="nav-pill">Social Media</div>
</div>
```

And here is the relevant CSS for it:

```
.nav-pill {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

I want my `nav-pill`s to grow my 10px whenever a mouse hovers on it. Since the flexbox adjusts it's size based on screen size, I can't animate with static values. So, I tried to do this:

```
var navPillHeight = $(".nav-pill").height();
var navPillWidth = $(".nav-pill").width(); 

$(".nav-pill").mouseenter(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: (navPillHeight+10)+"px",
        width: (navPillWidth+10)+"px",
    }, 200);
}).mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).animate({
        height: navPillHeight+"px",
        width: navPillWidth+"px"
    }, 200);});
```

But, for obvious reasons it wouldn't resize when the screen resized. So, I tried to do this:

```
function navPillResize() {
    var navPillHeight = $(".nav-pill").height();
    var navPillWidth = $(".nav-pill").width(); 

    $(".nav-pill").mouseenter(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: (navPillHeight+10)+"px",
            width: (navPillWidth+10)+"px",
        }, 200);
    }).mouseleave(function () {
        $(this).animate({
            height: navPillHeight+"px",
            width: navPillWidth+"px"
        }, 200);
    });
}

$(window).resize(navPillResize);
```

But, this did not work either, although the variable values did change. Does anybody have any solutions to this problem? Anything would help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you provide a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Comment: Yeah sure! Also, the relevant CSS was meant to say `#navbar` rather than `.nav-pill`.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/18t5feur/3/

Comment: If you increase the output window size to the max, you will see that the animation looks great, however, if you decrease the size, the animation does some jumbo mumbo stuff. If I try to bind a resize event, then pretty much nothing happens: https://jsfiddle.net/18t5feur/4/

Comment: Pls, someone help me